# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields_get' in Openerp

Tags: python, xml, odoo

why does this error occurs? is anyone familiar with this error. i got this error when i click any of the tabs eg: sales,purchase,human resource,accounting etc.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/osv/osv.py", line 122, in wrapper
return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/osv/osv.py", line 176, in execute
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/osv/osv.py", line 167, in execute_cr
return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/addons/hr/hr_department.py", line 94, in read
res = super(ir_action_window, self).read(cr, uid, select, fields=fields, context=context, load=load)
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/osv/orm.py", line 2944, in read
result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/osv/orm.py", line 3064, in _read_flat
res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, user, context=context, values=res)
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/osv/fields.py", line 800, in get
res = self._fnct(obj, cr, user, ids, name, self._arg, context)
File "/home/openERP/src/openerp-server/bin/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 193, in _search_view
fields_from_fields_get = self.pool.get(act.res_model).fields_get(cr, uid, context=context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields_get'
```

Comment: This is not a programming question and is probably better asked on the [OpenERP forums](http://www.openerp.com/forum/). From a quick search, looks like [others have reported similar symptoms](http://www.openerp.com/forum/post99663.html#p99663)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem in:

```
self.pool.get(act.res_model)
```

It should be the name which you are using `_name` attributes
Try with

```
self.pool.get(act.res.model)
```

Comment: thankyou for your help sir i just got another error along with this duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_module_module_certificate_uniq" . when i tracked that error i found that i had two account modules in my addons folder..when i deleted it the error got resloved..thankyou

Answer (score 2):

`self.pool.get(act.res_model)` is returning `None` (because the dictionary `pool` doesn't have an entry with the key `act.res_model`).

Therefore, the call `.fields_get(...)` on that object fails (because `None` obviously doesn't have such a method, which is what the error message is trying to tell you).